# How often is the number of downloads updated for a shared file?

Tags: email, files, contentdocument

I have been experimenting with list-emails with an attached file (the attachment is automatically replaced by Salesforce with a link to a preview/download location). I have personally downloaded a file from such an email. That was yesterday. The number of downloads for the file is still 0. I cannot find any documentation on the frequency of update of this field. Does anyone know?

Comment: You can use concept of tracking pixel, and put a hidden link/script and it'll automatically update the count. Not sure if its the best solution however if nothing works this can work for you.

Comment: @YsrShk I am using standard Salesforce functionality, it should track the number of downloads, but it doesn't seem to do so. There is not need for a tracking pixel, the mail contains a link to a URL on a Salesforce server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just got contacted by Salesforce Support. The problem is that the tracking of the number of downloads is only done for Salesforce users, not for people/customers who are not users.

The exact wording can be found [here](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_networks_file_detail_stats.htm): "Views and downloads through public links or content deliveries aren’t counted in the file engagement stats for files in the org."

To track public links and content deliveries you need to use something like Pardot or Marketing Cloud.